# How to properly populate the Google Chart (Map) with arrays instead of values

Tags: java, javascript, php, arrays, google-maps

I want to populate this google map - chart with the cities from the db, and the number of users from each city.

In order to do this, I have used the following code:

```
   <?      
    $query_city_users = "SELECT DISTINCT(city) FROM users 
                      WHERE approved = 1";
    $city_users = mysql_query($query_city_users, $con) or die(mysql_error());


       while ($row_city_users = mysql_fetch_assoc($city_users)) { 

            $query_users_from_city = "SELECT * FROM users 
                                     WHERE approved = 1 
                                     AND city= '".$row_city_users['city']."'";
            $users_from_city = mysql_query($query_users_from_city, $con) or die(mysql_error());
            $totalRows_users_from_city = mysql_num_rows($users_from_city); 
  ?>


               <?=$row_city_users['city'] ?> -
               <?=$totalRows_users_from_city ?> <br>
```

In PHP this outputs ok... it echoes the list of the cities and how many users are in each city.
The problem encountered is in my Charts Script attempt to populate with the data from the queries above.

```
   <!------ MAP CHARTS------->
   <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript'>
   google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

  function drawMarkersMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City',   'Users Number'],
    ['<?=$row_city_users['city'] ?>',  '<?=$totalRows_users_from_city ?>']

  ]);

  var options = {
    region: 'IT',
    displayMode: 'markers',
    colorAxis: {colors: ['lightblue', 'blue'],
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    keepAspectRatio: 'true',


    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('italy'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
</script> 

 <?  } // end while ?>
```

Using this code, the map only outputs a single city from the array...
I know I have missed something in the code, so please help...
My question would be how to properly populate the google chart with the arrays I have queried?

PS. I've read related questions on stackoverflow but they didn't help me with this case.

Comment: print data in console by using console.log(data) before drawing the chart. I think this data contains only single city

Comment: And if anyhow your drawMarkers is called from within any loop then you need to keep var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('italy')); at global level otherwise only last city will be plotted

Comment: I am certain that there are more than one cities.

Comment: sorry but I am not sure I understand second part...  Should i move this part  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('italy'));
      chart.draw(data, options);   outside the loop?

Comment: Only the first line. Leave chart.draw code as it is. You need not to create chart object every time in the loop

Comment: I've moved it below the  } // endwhile, but I got the same output.. only one city plotted.. the last one from my array...

Comment: yes, just now i spotted the error. You might need to create array in the loop and then draw the chart outside the loop. I will post a sample code in some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that your chart object is created a fresh every time within the loop. You can move the following code out of loop as

```
var rawData = [['City',   'Users Number']];
    var options = {
    region: 'IT',
    displayMode: 'markers',
    colorAxis: {colors: ['lightblue', 'blue'],
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    keepAspectRatio: 'true',
    }
```

Then replace your drawMarkersMap function with

```
function drawMarkersMap() {
    rawData.push(['<?=$row_city_users['city'] ?>',  '<?=$totalRows_users_from_city ?>']);
  };
```

Then again outside the loop you should use

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rawData);
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('italy'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Maintain the order of code. You may need to fix some minor bugs as I have no data to test

Comment: what lines of code should remain under the loop? because I have tested it and now it doesnt show the chart anymore, so it must be an error somewhere

Comment: After some tries, now the chart gives the error: "Incompatible data table: Error: Table contains more columns than expected (Expecting 2 columns)"

Comment: Only the drawMarkers should be inside the loop now. option and rawData should be declared before loop starts and data and chart should be defined after the loop

Comment: can you please put some code? How would you arrange it? Sorry, I have tried different arrangements but no result

Comment: My bad, I made an initialization mistake in rawData. Have edited my code now. Check, it should work now. If still you face a problem, i'll post a sample example